# What's the problem with question about number of guests in single hotel room?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Can someone explain me, what is the problem with [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/89457/15281)?

Why it was closed as too broad? It is absolutely specific and by no way too broad in my opinion. And the direct, precise answer to it seems it be confirming this fact.

In addition: Why I can't vote to open this question (no `reopen` link)?

Comment: Please reedit it to focus on one country. Afterwards I can reopen.

Comment: This is not my question, so I won't edit it. I'm asking to feed my curiosity. You haven't answered the second part -- why "reopen" link is missing?

Comment: Because you don't have 3000 rep.

Comment: Meaning that I completely misunderstood the "vote to reopen" idea? And without 3000 rep (don't have on any SE site) I can only VTC my own questions?

Comment: I will vote to reopen myself if someone edits that question to be less broad. And you are correct - you cannot vote to close/reopen until you have 3000 rep. See our privileges page: https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I think that asking "Do Hotel receipts show number of guests?" is too broad since it will inevitably depend on the country, the establishment and a combination of both. Reducing the scope to one country might help in making it less broad.

The reason you cannot see the close/reopen link is because [that is a privilege which is unlocked at 3000 reputation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). To date you don't have 3000 reputation.

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me. "There's no one simple answer for all cases because..." is a useful and valid type of answer.

Comment: @user568458 Unfortunately we tend to close questions with such an answer since they are too broad.

Comment: Well, don't then.............

Comment: @user568458 I don't make the rules.

Comment: @JoErNanO You're the diamond moderator. Who then does make rules, if not you? The community? SE?

Comment: @trejder SE decides the format of their sites, the community decides what is on and off-topic for this site. [Moderators are just human exception handlers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/), not dictators.